# Apache HTTP Client - Issues with 0 leased connections in Apache Http client

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am trying to use PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager in our module.

Below is my code snippet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpRoute;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.entity.EntityUtils;

public class Testme {
    static PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager;
    static CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(3);
        connectionManager.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(new HttpHost("http://127.0.0.1",8887)), 5);
        httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();
        System.out.println("Available connections "+connectionManager.getTotalStats().getAvailable());
        System.out.println("Max Connections "+connectionManager.getTotalStats().getMax());
        System.out.println("Number of routes "+connectionManager.getRoutes().size());
        Testme testme = new Testme();
        Testme.ThreadMe threads[] = new Testme.ThreadMe[5];
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) 
            threads[i] = testme.new ThreadMe();

        for(Testme.ThreadMe thread:threads) { 
            System.out.println("Leased connections before assigning "+connectionManager.getTotalStats().getLeased());
            thread.start(); 
        }
    }

    class ThreadMe extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                CloseableHttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1:8887"));
                System.out.println("Req for "+Thread.currentThread().getName() + " executed with "+response);
                try {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                }catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();    
                }
                finally {   
                    response.close();
                } 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the output i received was as below:

```
Available connections 0
Max Connections 25
Number of routes 0
Leased connections before assigning 0
Leased connections before assigning 0
Leased connections before assigning 0
Leased connections before assigning 0
Leased connections before assigning 0
Req for Thread-2 executed with 200 OK HTTP/1.1
Req for Thread-4 executed with 200 OK HTTP/1.1
Req for Thread-3 executed with 200 OK HTTP/1.1
Req for Thread-0 executed with 200 OK HTTP/1.1
Req for Thread-1 executed with 200 OK HTTP/1.1
```

I am unable to find my leased connections are always 0 though there are requests executing. Also, the routes are always shown as 0 though I have registered the route. It seems to me that there is some problem but I could not identify it. Available connections are also shown as 0 during execution(though it is not printed here). Please help me in finding out what went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first print of *"Available connections"* message is of course 0, as only after you'll get the response and it'll be decided, based on default strategies **DefaultClientConnectionReuseStrategy** & **DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy**, if the connection should be reusable, and for how long, only then the connection will be moved to *available connections list*.

I'm guessing that the *number of routes* is also decided after at least one connection was created.

In your log you can see that the main thread printed all the *"Leased connections before assigning"* messages **before** the child threads ran, and so you see 0 leased connections.
A connection exists in *leased connections list* only from the time of creation until the releasing time, that usually happens on *response.readEntity()*, *response.close()*, the closing of the connection manager, and maybe on *EntityUtils.consume()* as well.

So maybe try to move the "*Leased connections before assigning*" from the main thread to child thread.